# Checkstyle, missing space after anonymous inner class

Tags: java, whitespace, checkstyle, curly-braces

Given the following snippet of code:

```java
public void doSomething() {
    new Executor() {
        @Override
        public void doStuff() {
            // ...
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

...Checkstyle complains that there is no space after the closing brace of the anonymous inner class.

Note that the following snippet does not trigger the warning:

```java
public void doSomething() {
    Executor exec = new Executor() {
        @Override
        public void doStuff() {
            // ...
        }
    };
    exec.execute()
}
```

I have tried to configure the checker as below, to no avail:

```xml
<module name="WhitespaceAround">
    <property name="allowEmptyConstructors" value="true"/>
</module>
```

How can I configure Checkstyle so that it ignores cases like the one from the first snippet ?